# Realm how to write subquery

Tags: swift, nspredicate, realm

I am study about Realm db, this db is nice as compare with core data but I am stuck on one place as follows:

I have two RLMObject in that I created relationship and I want to run join query (sub query) on that, but I can't do that.

---

first object (table) in Ralm

```
class Dog : RLMObject
{
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var age = 0

    // create variable of Owner object 
    dynamic var owner = RLMArray(objectClassName: "Owner")

    override class func primaryKey() -> String!{
        return "name"
    }
}
```

second object (table) in Ralm

```
class Owner : RLMObject{
    dynamic var myName = ""
}
```

so I want to fetch only those Dog names which belong with owner name 'ram'
I tried following sub query

```
var dog = Dog.allObjects().objectsWithPredicate(NSPredicate(format:"SUBQUERY(Owner, $owner, $owner.myName = 'ram')", argumentArray: nil))
```

but app is crashing with following error

```
RealTest[1701:17960] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "SUBQUERY(owner, $owner, $owner.myName = 'ram')"'
```

also I search it on net I found that realm.objects but it gave me error about not found.
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The relationships in your case seem to be questionable. A dog can have multiple owners?

Comment: yes, actually I just learn realm now. that why I taking that example

Answer (score 5):

Your predicate should look like this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"SUBQUERY(Owner, $owner, $owner.myName = 'ram') .@count > 0", argumentArray: nil)
```

The idea here is to make sure you add `.@ count > 0` at the end, as the predicate needs to return `true` or `false` for it to work.

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved using a query like:

```
Dog.allObjects().objectsWhere("ANY owner.myName = 'ram'")
```

`SUBQUERY` is only necessary if you have multiple constraints on the target of the relationship that must all be fulfilled by a single row, or if you wish to express a constraint other than `ANY` / `ALL` / `NONE` on the number of rows that match.

That said, as of [Realm Objective-C and Swift 0.98.0](https://realm.io/news/realm-objc-swift-0.98.0/) `SUBQUERY` is now supported.

Answer (score 0):

While Realm supports filtering objects via `NSPredicate`, at this time of writing, Realm's implementation of `NSPredicate` yet support every single type of keyword that the native Apple frameworks do, including SUBQUERY. Realm provides an [`NSPredicate` cheat sheet](https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/) on its website, outlining which types of queries it presently supports.

That being said, if you already have an `Owner` object at this point, you can actually use another Realm method on the `Owner` object ([[RLMObject linkingObjectsOfClass:forProperty:]](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#//api/name/linkingObjectsOfClass:forProperty:)) to find out which `Dog` objects are referencing it.

Finally, that `realm.objects` error is because that syntax is from the native Swift version of Realm, and the code you're using here is the Objective-C version of Realm, bridged over to Swift.

Let me know if you need any more clarification!

Comment: Thanks. 1. can you please give me that query for better understanding. 2. I have downloaded swift realm version then also why it give me error on realm.objects. if you know any proper document/website for implementing realm in swift (with out objective-c) please send me those links. Thanks

Comment: No problems! In that context, I believe it would be `let dogs = owner.linkingObjectsOfClass("Dog", forProperty:"owner")`. All of the documentation for Realm Swift is available at: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

Comment: I am confused about this versions of objective-c bridge and native swift. so which query gives me where it will support. or better way I delete my objective-c bridge code and older real framework and download new swift native realm framework ver. 0.95.2 ?

Comment: `SUBQUERY` is not supported in any version of Realm at the moment. Sorry!

Comment: So how I will do that. Is there any other way to do that (subquery task)

Comment: Unfortunately, for the time being, I think you'll have to implement that in code yourself.